# Dialog does not appear

Tags: android, dialog

I use following code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        Button bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        activity = this;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage("message")
           .setTitle("title");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAdd:
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

But for some reason my popup doesn't appear and does nothing at all.. Any ideas on what is causing this malfunction? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call `show()` method instead of `create()`.

**Note:** `create()` method only creates instance of `Dialog` but it won't show its.

One suggestion:

You can create method that returns `Dialog` like this:

```
public Dialog createNewDialog(int type) {
   AlertDialog dlg = null;
   switch (type) {
      case SOME_CONSTANT:
         dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this / this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", null)
            .create();
      break;
   }
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
createNewDialog(SOME_CONSTANT).show();
```

and your `Dialog` will be shown.

Especially in your case you can reach your goal with this snippet of code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAdd:
            createNewDialog(SOME_CONSTANT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you might know a solution to my other problem as well? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362396/dialog-layout-double-layered-wrong-transparant-background Quite stuck there...

Answer (score 9):

I have this issue and maybe this answer can help someone.

I was running the code to show the AlertDialog on a non-ui thread. After using:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ShowAlert();
        }
    });
```

the AlertDialog worked.

Comment: This happened to me

Answer (score 1):

you need to call  `builder.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somehow similar problem, in my case the dialog would appear and disappear in milliseconds: To solve it, don't call finish() or finishActivity() in the same method that calls your dialog.

```
createNewDialog(SOME_CONSTANT).show();
finish();
```

this destroys your dialog even before you access it.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is not showing is that `.show()` was not called on the `AlertDialog`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAdd:
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
        }

    }
```